# D3 date format throwing 'd.getFullYear is not a function'

Tags: javascript, d3.js

According to [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting):

- `%y` - year without century as a decimal number [00,99].
- `%b` - abbreviated month name.
- `%d` - zero-padded day of the month as a decimal number [01,31].

So I thought this should parse correctly to the 26th December 2009:

```
var date = d3.time.format('%y-%b-%d')('09-Dec-26');
```

... but instead it throws an exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: d.getFullYear is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `.parse`:

```
var date = d3.time.format('%y-%b-%d').parse('09-Dec-26');
```

The return for `d3.time.format` is not a function, so you can't just call it with another parameter. Instead it's an object with methods that can be called. One of those methods is `.parse`.

```js
var date = d3.time.format('%y-%b-%d').parse('09-Dec-26');
document.querySelector("#date").textContent = date
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: That's exactly it.  Thanks!